# Companion Apple Watch App local notifications delayed?

Tags: ios, swift, watchos

I have an app for Apple Watch as a companion app for an iPhone app. The local notifications on Apple Watch App are delayed. I scheduled a local notification to be fired after 10 seconds. When I press the button on the watch that creates the notification and I exit the app, it doesn't take 10 seconds to display the notification but about 23 seconds.

I created a test stand alone/independent Apple Watch App with the same local notification code, and in this scenario, the local notification fires at the correct time.

I am on watchOS 8.1. Is this a new feature on Apple Watch or a bug? Because on iPhone it works without any delay. Thank you in advance :)

```
// Configure the notification's payload. 
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Drink some milk!"
    content.subtitle = "you have 10 sec"
    content.sound = .default
    content.categoryIdentifier = "myCategory"
    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "myCategory", actions: [], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "milk", content: content, trigger: trigger)
     
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
      if let error = error{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }else{
        print("scheduled successfully")
      }
    }
```

Comment: same issue at watchos 8.3

Answer (score 3):

There is a feedback here:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696280

> This is correct behaviour.

> If you have both a phone and watch app installed we’ll try to coordinate between phone and watch notifications if the phone is unlocked. If the app developer doesn’t send a notification on the phone the watch will timeout after 13 seconds and alert anyway.

> The best solution to this would be to send the same notification on both devices ensuring the UNNotificationRequest.identifier matches on a per-instance basis.

> This will let us alert and deduce correctly.

If watch app send local notification , `I'll send the notification 13 seconds ahead of time`.  This way the notification appears to be on time

Hope to have a better solution in the future

Comment: It also seems that the minimum time in the future to send a watchOS local notification(which will be delivered) is 3 seconds. So with the installed companion app we can receive it earliest in 16 seconds.

Is there a reliable way to find out if the 13 second delay will be applied by watchOS?